# Swift, tableview doesn't get populated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift and i've been working on an app for a couple of day now. Now I'm trying to fill up my tableview, but for some reason it stays empty. I've checked if my data comes through (by doing a print of my drinks in the updateUi function), and it seems so be there but my view just doesn't get filled. Anyone has a clue what could be wrong?

Thanks a lot!

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  let cocktailController = CocktailController()
  var drinks = [Drink]()
  var drink: String!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          title = drink.capitalized
          cocktailController.fetchDrinks(forDrink: drink)
          { (drinks) in
              if let drinks = drinks {
                  self.updateUI(with: drinks)
              }
          }
      }

    func updateUI(with drinks: [Drink]) {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.drinks = drinks
              self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
    }

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
      // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
      return drinks.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt
  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
  "DrinkCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
      configure(cell, forItemAt: indexPath)
      return cell
  }

  func configure(_ cell: UITableViewCell, forItemAt indexPath:
  IndexPath) {
      let drinkItem = drinks[indexPath.row]
      cell.textLabel?.text = drinkItem.strDrink

  }
}
```

Comment: from your code above, I can’t see the implementation of the method numberOfRowsInSection, is that missing? try returning 1 un the numberOfSection and move the drink count in the missing delegate method mentioned before, should help

Comment: Wauw I didn't see I didn't implement numberOfRowsInsection, instead I Implemented numberOfSections... Thank you Luca! I was struggling like crazy

Comment: glad it helps 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of number of sections, you should use number of rows in section to return the tableview row count.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
return drinks.count
}
```